# Pass pointer of an object built in javascript land to webassembly (C++) function

Tags: javascript, webassembly

I have a function in C++ that takes a `(const char*)` argument. I want to call this function in JavaScript (through Web assembly) by passing to it the address of an object created in JavaScript. Is this possible?

The code is something like

```
// Create an object by loading from url.
const encoder = await loadModel("some_url");
const data = [1,2,3];

Module.onRuntimeInitialized = _ => {
  // Call the wasm function with a pointer to the encoder.
  Module.encode(&encoder, data);
}
```

How can I take the address of the encoder object to pass to the function?

Comment: No, you cannot access pointers in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is common to serialize the JavaScript object to a primitive string to pass between programming languages.

Comment: Are you generalizing? WebAssembly does not have strings. JavaScript and WebAssembly can only share a block of memory. Passing simple data back and forth requires a lot of glue code.